# Must I implement siteverify request on server side when using reCAPTCHA v2 invisible?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

After perfectly working on client side for reCAPTCHA v2 invisible, I had an alert at admin console for reCAPTCHA, which says

```
We have detected that your site has not been validated the reCAPTCHA solution.
Proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site requires validation. For more information,
see Google's developer site.
```

I know that current implementation of mine is improper and that this error means we should implement the verification process on servers.

However, if I implemented it on the servers, it will prolong processes on the servers because of requesting to siteverify API and the servers will have a possibility to be down. So I want to avoid it. For me, popping up "choose cars or ships" verification on the client side is enough to pass users through our service. No more implementation is needed.

Actually, even if it must be required to get-go, I can construct an architecture using AWS Lambda, API Gateway or the likes, but I would also like to avoid using this kind of silly option only for reCAPTCHA.

The thing I want to ask is "Is there a problem if I ignore the alert message?"

If I ignore the alert message, continue on using reCAPTCHA v2 invisible, am I banned from Google? If so, definitely it will be a disaster.

Could you help me by your knowledge? Any clues are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer, but as far as I searched for this problem, **no ban occurred even though we don't use siteverify.**

Disclaimer: This result comes from performances of other services. Not as an official information.

However, that no banning happened doesn't mean we can completely escape from the fear for banning by Google.

So I concluded we MUST implement the server-side siteverify request to run services reliably.